# Can you help me model this shell shape?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to recreate this shape as closely as possible (the "shell", not the ring)

I can make a sphere and flatten it to the proper dimensions, but the radius is never the same near the "points" of the almond shape.

Thanks for your help!

[image: almond shape top]
[image: almond shape side]
[image: almond shape front]
[image: almond shape three quarter]
[image: almond shape the other quarter]
[image: flattened sphere in blender]
[image: reference image in blender]

Answer (score 3):

You could begin with a circle that you scale on Z and extrude inwards:

[image]

Then switch to side view and give it the right curvy profile:

[image]

Comment: I see, so once i am on the profile, should I use scale to fit the shape? Also, if I want to 3D print the item, how can I keep the resolution high? I can see that you only have a few loop to move. Thanks

Comment: once in side view, select the central circle and move it to the left. You can enable the Proportional Editing option if you want to move the other circles as well. If you want a high resolution, give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier and apply it, but before that, give your object thickness with a Solidify modifier that you apply and also create edge loops along the edges in order to sharp them.

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot, I'll try this tonight.ß